# How to replace text to make class of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, addclass

Trying to replace text to class of a div. Means find text from `.label` *(text1 or any text)*, then replace it as class `class="text1"` to parent list `<li>` item like `<li class="text1">`. Example given below

**HTML**:

This is main output html code.

```
<div id="main-id">
<ul>

<li> <!--List 1-->
<span class="meta">
<div class="label">
<a href="http://lorem.com">text1</a>
</div>
</span>
</li>

<li> <!--List 2-->
<span class="meta">
<div class="label">
<a href="http://lorem.com">text2</a>
</div>
</span>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

By Jquery/JS output html like this: (I want this)

```
<div id="main-id">
<ul>

<li class="text1"> <!--Add class to List 1-->

<span class="meta">
<div class="label">
<a href="http://lorem.com">text1</a> <!--Get class name from here-->
</div>
</span>
</li>

<li class="text2"> <!--Add class List 2-->

<span class="meta">
<div class="label">
<a href="http://lorem.com">text2</a> <!--Get class name from here-->
</div>
</span>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

I am using this Replace text [script](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-replacetext/examples/replacetext/), but i unable to do that.
Any suggestion for other way to do this? 
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `addClass()` to add class

```js
$('.label a').each(function() {
   var $this=$(this);      
   $this.closest('li').addClass($this.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-id">
  <ul>

    <li>
      <!--List 1-->
      <span class="meta">
<div class="label">
<a href="http://lorem.com">text1</a>
</div>
</span>
    </li>

    <li>
      <!--List 2-->
      <span class="meta">
<div class="label">
<a href="http://lorem.com">text2</a>
</div>
</span>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Aabira : glad to help :)

Comment: Hi, are you there? This is my question for you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32163672/4290783

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ts8Lcpa/)

```
function replace(){

    var arr = [];

    $('div .label').each( function(){ // search for divs with a label
        arr.push( $(this).text() );
    });

    // add class to each <li>
    $('li').each( function(index, element){
        $(this).addClass(arr[index]);
    });
}

replace();
```

Answer (score 1):

use for each `$('li)`

`addClass()` can add class. Or use `attr()` method.

Comment: $('li) - won't return anything