# Add and Remove class to click a dynamic Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addclass, removeclass

Trying to Add and Remove class to click dynamic Buttons, means this button `<button class="one"></button>` get class dynamically like this: `<button class="one text1">text1</button>` 

So if *button one* has class `.text1` and by *click* this add class `.hide` to list item `<li class="text1">` like `<li class="text1 show">`

Same for *button two* `<button class="two"></button>` and by click add class `<li class="text2 show">`

Note: when click *button two*, then should remove class `.show` and add new class `.hide`to *button one*.

**Main HTML:**

```
<div id="main-id">
    <button class="one"></button>
    <button class="two"></button>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <!--List 1-->
            <div class="label">
                <a href="#">text1</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <!--List 2 is Same-->
            <div class="label">
                <a href="#">text1</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <!--List 3 is different-->
            <div class="label">
                <a href="#">text2</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
$('.label a').each(function() {
   var $this=$(this);      
   $this.closest('li').addClass($this.text());
});

// Combine This

$('button').each(function(){
    var liInd = 0;
    var cl = '';
    var txt = '';
    var clses = [];

    var ind = $('button').index($(this)) + 1;

    $('li').each(function(){
        if(clses.indexOf($(this).attr('class')) === -1){
            clses.push($(this).attr('class'));
            liInd = liInd + 1;
        }

        if(ind === liInd){
            cl = $(this).attr('class');
            txt = $(this).find('a').text();
            return false; //break
        }
    });

    $('button:nth-child(' + ind + ')').addClass(cl);
    $('button:nth-child(' + ind + ')').text(txt);
});
```

See [Example on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yaLm4euk/)

I have tried this by add/remove class by click function, but problem is Buttons get class dynamically from List items, so I'm not able to target button.
 
Any suggestion for other way to do this by *JS/ Jquery*?

Comment: your question is not clear enough.

Comment: I mean want to add/remove class to list items by click function.

Comment: check this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yaLm4euk/1/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution

```
$('button').each(function () {
    var liInd = 0;
    var cl = '';
    var txt = '';
    var clses = [];

    var ind = $('button').index($(this)) + 1;

    $('li').each(function () {
        if (clses.indexOf($(this).attr('class')) === -1) {
            clses.push($(this).attr('class'));
            liInd = liInd + 1;
        }

        if (ind === liInd) {
            cl = $(this).attr('class');
            txt = $(this).find('a').text();
            return false; //break
        }
    });

    if (txt != '') {
        $('button:nth-child(' + ind + ')').addClass(cl);
        $('button:nth-child(' + ind + ')').text(txt);
    }
});

$('button').click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('class')[0] == 'all') {
        showAll();
        return false; // end this function
    }

    var allCls = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');



    $('li').each(function () {

        if (allCls.indexOf($(this).find('a').text()) > -1) {
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
        }
    });
});

function showAll() {
    $('li').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/yaLm4euk/13/

Comment: Hi Taleeb, thanks, i have add text `ALL` to `<button class="all">All</button>`, but this text getting remove from `<button class="all"></button>`! please fix this.

Comment: but this text `ALL` getting remove from <button class="all"> All</button>! please fix this.

Comment: I mean new text `ALL` getting remove from `<button class="all"> All</button>`. I have added ALL text to <button class="all"> text here</button> , please see this: https://jsfiddle.net/yaLm4euk/15/

Comment: Yes - the code should work on IE9 (but jsFiddle probably won't)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87692/discussion-between-aabira-and-taleeb).

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/yaLm4euk/2/)

```js
$('.label a').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('li').addClass($this.text());
});

// Combine This
$('button').each(function () {
    var liInd = 0;
    var cl = '';
    var txt = '';
    var clses = [];
    var ind = $('button').index($(this)) + 1;
    $('li').each(function () {
        if (clses.indexOf($(this).attr('class')) === -1) {
            clses.push($(this).attr('class'));
            liInd = liInd + 1;
        }
        if (ind === liInd) {
            cl = $(this).attr('class');
            txt = $(this).find('a').text();
            return false; //break
        }
    });
    $('button:nth-child(' + ind + ')').addClass(cl);
    $('button:nth-child(' + ind + ')').text(txt);
});
$(document).on('click', 'button',function(e){
    var textClass = $.grep(this.className.split(" "), function(v, i){
       return v.indexOf('text') === 0;
    }).join();
    console.log(textClass);
    $('li').removeClass('show').addClass('hide')
    $('li').each(function(){
     if($(this).hasClass($.trim(textClass))){
         $(this).removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
        }
    })
})
```

```css
.show{display:list-item;}
.hide{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-id">
        <button class="one"></button>
        <button class="two"></button>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <!--List 1-->
                <div class="label">
    <a href="#">text1</a>

                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <!--List 2 is Same-->
                <div class="label">
    <a href="#">text1</a>

                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <!--List 3 is different-->
                <div class="label">
    <a href="#">text2</a>

                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Wow, it works, one little more thing is, if want to show all items by click new button name `all` / `<button class="all"> </button>`  then add class `.show-all `, then what it should be? see this fiddle please: https://jsfiddle.net/yaLm4euk/3/

Comment: @Aabira you can do something like this. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/yaLm4euk/9/) using some conditions.

Comment: thanks, i have add text `ALL` to `<button class="all">All</button>`, but this text getting remove from `<button class="all"></button>`! please fix this.

Comment: @Aabira your function was returning null for the variable `txt` in the case of last button. [**FIX**](https://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/yaLm4euk/14/). `txt = txt || 'all';`